# block the impact of the orphanRemoval jpa keyword in the 2nd table

Tags: java, jpa

Is is possible to block the impact of the *orphanRemoval* jpa keyword in the 2nd. table?

I have this databas structure:

```
 car                  bus
 1|                   1|
  |                    |
  |                    |
car_attribute (link table)
           *|
        attribute
           1|
            |
           *|
      attribute_name
```

Java entity classes:

Car.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name="CAR_ATTRIBUTE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ATTRIBUTE_ID"))
private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Attribute.java

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private AttributeName attributeName;
```

Data in tables:

```
CAR
pk|color|...
1  red
2  green

CAR_ATTRIBUTE
car_id|attribute_id
1      10
1      11
1      12
2      20
2      21
2      22

ATTRIBUTE
id|attribute_name_id|value
10| 100             | a
11| 101             | b
12| 102             | c
20| 103             | d
21| 103             | e
22| 101             | f

ATTRIBUTE_NAME
pk | name|... 
100| 
101|
...
```

I use this code to insert/update data into database via jpa. Everything works fine.

```
public void update(Car car)
{
    try
    {
    Car queryResult = (Car) em.createNamedQuery("Car.findBy...").setParameter("...", param).getSingleResult();

    // existing car, perform update
    // do something...
    car.setId(queryResult.getId());
    car.getAttributes().clear();
    updateAttributes(profile.getAttributes());
    em.merge(car);
    }
    catch (NoResultException e)
    {
    // new car, perform insert
    // do something else...
    // avoid "detached entity passed to persist" exception
    profile.setId(null);
    updateAttributes(profile.getAttributes());
    em.merge(profile);
    }


private void updateAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes)
{
    for (Attribute attribute : attributes)
    {
    attribute.setId(null);

    try
    {
        AttributeName queryResult = (AttributeName) em.createNamedQuery("AttributeName.findByName").setParameter("name", attribute.getAttributeName().getName()).getSingleResult();
        if (queryResult != null)
        {
        attribute.getAttributeName().setId(queryResult.getId());
        }
    }
    catch (NoResultException e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    }
}
```

I would like to keep in the database the all existing records in the ATTRIBUTE_NAME table when I update/delete records in ATTRIBUTE table.
But car.getAttributes().clear() clean everything. It cleans records from CAR_ATTRIBUTE, ATTRIBUTE and ATTRIBUTE_NAME tables. But I want to keep records in the ATTRIBUTE_NAME table.

How can I manage this relationship with jpa?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have orphan removal set on the Car ->Attribute relationship if you want Attributes to exist when you call car.getAttributes().clear();  Why not just remove the flag?   JPA will still maintain the CAR_ATTRIBUTE join table for you, removing references when attributes are dereferenced.

Comment: If i remove orphan then the relationships are removed automatically by jpa but items in the attribute table still remain and I need to delete them manually.

Comment: so you want Attributes deleted when dereferenced, but not the referenced AttributeNames?  Remove the cascade = CascadeType.ALL setting on the relationship or change it to something more appropriate for what you want, so that it doesn't cascade the remove operation to the referenced  AttributeName instances

Comment: thank you for your help. The solution as you suggested is: orphanRemoval = true on Car and cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH} on Attribute.